# Custom Mailer Undefined Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer, mandrill

I have a custom mailer that inherits from Devise.

Here is my controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 def create
  super
  if @user.persisted?
   CustomMailer.new_registration(self).deliver
  end
 end
end
```

Here is the mailer:

```
class CustomMailer < Devise::Mailer   

def new_registration(user)
 @user = user
 mandrill_mail(
  template: 'New User Welcome',
  to: @user.email,
  vars: {
    'USER_FIRST_NAME' => user.first_name,
  },
  important: true,
  inline_css: true,
  async: true
 )
 end
end
```

I feel like I have tried every possibility, but always get a NoMethodError like this: *undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass*

So for some reason my mailer isn't able to access my model...

I'm using Rails 4 and Devise 3.2.4 if that makes any difference, as well as Mandrill Mailer.

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated. Been on this for a couple hours now.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `self` in the `RegistrationsController` when you need to be passing `@user`:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 def create
  super
  if @user.persisted?
   CustomMailer.new_registration(@user).deliver
  end
 end
end
```

`self` in this case is an instance of the controller, not the `User` record you need in the mailer.